# Shopify: Show multiple collections on one page

Tags: shopify

In the image below, you can see I've managed to make a drop down menu in a Shopify store. The drop down menu contains some collections. My question is: when user clicks on "Men's" s/he's directed to a certain collection (right now: Walk shorts).

Is it possible that when user clicks on "Men's", s/he's presented with all the collections that you see in that drop down menu?

[image: ss]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using tags.

Have all you product in those collection tagged with the tag "men", then simply have the top link to `/collections/all/men`

http://docs.shopify.com/manual/your-store/products/edit-tags

Comment: Will they still be categorized as walk shorts, hybrid shorts etc or will it just be a long list of products?

Answer (score 0):

Charles is right, you can do this with tags.

I suggest taking a look at this article in the Shopify docs: 
[Creating subcategories of products](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/collections/subcategories). It explains how to create subcategories with tags and gives a few examples of how to display them on one page.